# How to share webpack result between frontend and backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, frontend, backend

I have two projects - frontend (vue) and backend (nodejs) - of one web app. I'm using webpack to build frontend. All images change their names to hashes during building. Now i need to know some of them at backend side. What is best way to share that info between frontend and backend?

I can use simple hardcoding approach or rely on custom hand-written mapping and use custom script to load assets. But both of these are fragile approach.

Webpack allows multi-build projects using `target`. Exactly, how to achieve this using Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack programmatic can help you webpack Node API

```
// webpack/script.js
import webpack from "webpack";

const compiler = webpack({ /* your config*/ }, (err, stats) => {
  // stats.toJson(options)
  console.log(stats.toString())

  // make api call for getting the info in backend with stats of your choice 
})
```